# interpolating in R yearly time series data with quarterly values

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, interpolation, zoo

I have a data set that has a list of IDs, year, and income. I am trying to interpolate the yearly values to quarterly values.

```
id = c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,4,4,4,5,5)
year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000,2001,2002, 2000,2001,2002,2000,2002)
income = c(20, 24, 26, 30,34,36, 40,46,48,53,56)
df = data.frame(id, year, income)
```

For e.g., I am looking to get the values of (interpolated) income for year-quarter 2000Q1, 2000Q2, 2000Q3, 2000Q4, 2001Q1, ... , 2001Q4. So the dataframe would be id,year-quarter, income. The income would be based on interpolated income.

I realize when linear interpolating, the trend must only be based on the respective IDs. Any suggestions on how I would do the interpolation in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

annual_data <- data.frame(
    person=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
    year=c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2012),
    y=c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3)
    )

expand_data <- function(x) {
    years <- min(x$year):max(x$year)
    quarters <- 1:4
    grid <- expand.grid(quarter=quarters, year=years)
    x$quarter <- 1
    merged <- grid %>% left_join(x, by=c('year', 'quarter'))
    merged$person <- x$person[1]
    return(merged)
}

interpolate_data <- function(data) {
    xout <- 1:nrow(data)
    y <- data$y
    interpolation <- approx(x=xout[!is.na(y)], y=y[!is.na(y)], xout=xout)
    data$yhat <- interpolation$y
    return(data)
}

expand_and_interpolate <- function(x) interpolate_data(expand_data(x))

quarterly_data <- annual_data %>% group_by(person) %>% do(expand_and_interpolate(.))

print(as.data.frame(quarterly_data))
```

The output from this approach is:

```
   quarter year person  y yhat
1        1 2010      1  1 1.00
2        2 2010      1 NA 1.25
3        3 2010      1 NA 1.50
4        4 2010      1 NA 1.75
5        1 2011      1  2 2.00
6        2 2011      1 NA 2.25
7        3 2011      1 NA 2.50
8        4 2011      1 NA 2.75
9        1 2012      1  3 3.00
10       2 2012      1 NA   NA
11       3 2012      1 NA   NA
12       4 2012      1 NA   NA
13       1 2010      2  1 1.00
14       2 2010      2 NA 1.25
15       3 2010      2 NA 1.50
16       4 2010      2 NA 1.75
17       1 2011      2 NA 2.00
18       2 2011      2 NA 2.25
19       3 2011      2 NA 2.50
20       4 2011      2 NA 2.75
21       1 2012      2  3 3.00
22       2 2012      2 NA   NA
23       3 2012      2 NA   NA
24       4 2012      2 NA   NA
```

There are probably a bunch of ways to clean this up. The key functions being used are `expand.grid`, `approx`, and `dplyr::group_by`. The `approx` function is a little tricky. Looking at the implementation of `zoo::na.approx.default` was quite helpful in figuring out how to work with `approx`.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use this convention to split a dataframe into subsets (unique values of 'id' in your case), apply a function to each subset, then put the data frame back together.

```
df2 <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$id), function(df_subset) {

  # the operations inside these brackets will be appied to a subset dataframe
  #   that is equivalent to doing 'subset(df, id == x)' where x is each unique value of id

  return(df_subset) # this just returns df_subset unchanged, but you alter it in any way you need

}))
```

There are a few ways to do linear interpolation, but I personally default to using na.approx() from the 'zoo' package. You'll need to add rows representing each quarter to your dataframe, with NA for their `income` value. Then na.approx will fill them in with an interpolated value, as in `df_subset$income_interpolated <- na.approx(df_subset$income)`