# filling missing values time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, zoo, missing-data

I am trying to expand yearly values in my panel data to year-quarter values. That is repeat the yearly values to every quarter. 
For e.g., I am looking to get the repeated values of income for year-quarter 2000Q1, 2000Q2, 2000Q3, 2000Q4, 2001Q1, ... , 2001Q4. So the data frame would be id,year-quarter, income.

I use a two step approach but have some issues to handle. If the quarterly starting value is missing, then I would then need to the quarterly to be missing  (NA) too.

Case 1:

```
annual_data <- data.frame(
person=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2),
year=c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012),
income=c(4, 10, 13, 1, NA, 30)
)
```

Case 2:

```
annual_data <- data.frame(
person=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2),
year=c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012),
income=c(4, 10, 13, NA, NA, 30)
)
```

In the first step, I expand the data to quarterly as was mentioned:
[interpolating in R yearly time series data with quarterly values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320727/interpolating-in-r-yearly-time-series-data-with-quarterly-values/32357068#32357068)

So use a function such as:

```
expand <- function(x) {
    years <- min(x$year):max(x$year)
    quarters <- 1:4
    grid <- expand.grid(quarter=quarters, year=years)
    x$quarter <- 1
    merged <- grid %>% left_join(x, by=c('year', 'quarter'))
    merged$person <- x$person[1]
    return(merged)
   }
```

Then I used in

```
    zoo::na.locf 

    dplyr::mutate.

quarterlydata <- annual_data %>% group_by(person) %>% do(expand(.))
testdata <- quarterlydata %>% group_by(person) %>% mutate(ynew=zoo::na.locf(y))
```

but havent had much luck as it copies forward to all missing values from the previous non-missing values. That is,

Case 1: it copies all values, So income of 1 for person 2 gets copied over to 2010 and 2011. When it must be copied over to just 2010, and 2011 should be NAs.

For case 2: I get

```
 Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1.
```

Any thoughts on where I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case 1 you are missing the year in your `group_by`. Since using the code that you have, the groupings for `na.locf` thinks that `year` is part of the grouping which `na.locf` must run over.

```
testdata <- quarterlydata %>% 
  group_by(person, year) %>% 
  mutate(ynew=zoo::na.locf(income, na.rm=FALSE))
```

With the output:

```
> tail(testdata, 13)
Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
Groups: person, year

   quarter year person income ynew
1        4 2012      1     NA   13
2        1 2010      2      1    1
3        2 2010      2     NA    1
4        3 2010      2     NA    1
5        4 2010      2     NA    1
6        1 2011      2     NA   NA
7        2 2011      2     NA   NA
8        3 2011      2     NA   NA
9        4 2011      2     NA   NA
10       1 2012      2     30   30
11       2 2012      2     NA   30
12       3 2012      2     NA   30
13       4 2012      2     NA   30
```

For case 2, as you might already infer from the code above, you must have `na.rm` set to `FALSE` otherwise the vector will drop off all `NA` which it could not extrapolate.

So using exactly the same code for case 2 we will have the output:

```
> tail(testdata, 13)
Source: local data frame [13 x 5]
Groups: person, year

   quarter year person income ynew
1        4 2012      1     NA   13
2        1 2010      2     NA   NA
3        2 2010      2     NA   NA
4        3 2010      2     NA   NA
5        4 2010      2     NA   NA
6        1 2011      2     NA   NA
7        2 2011      2     NA   NA
8        3 2011      2     NA   NA
9        4 2011      2     NA   NA
10       1 2012      2     30   30
11       2 2012      2     NA   30
12       3 2012      2     NA   30
13       4 2012      2     NA   30
```